# AddressBook like Outlook

Tags: html, css, addressbook

I would like to implement a sort of AddressBook like the one in outlook as in the following picture

[image]

Can somebody help with markup and style for the address card?

Comment: What have you tried so far? People here aren't usually inclined to "give you the codes" if you try it out first and it fails, most people will be willing to help, although there are some that will just do it for you, if they have time :)

Comment: @Kyle: you're right and I am sorry for that but I have a very very poor knowledge of html and css. I just dont know where to start for the vertical side for example... :(

Comment: No need to apologise, I'd suggest using three divs, one on top, two underneath. I do actually have some time so I'll try to code a quick guide for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a quick example for you: You can see it [live here on jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/f5YxG/).

HTML:

```
<div class="outl-add">
    <div class="outl-add-top">
       Duck, Daffy
    </div>
    <div class="outl-add-left-vert">
       &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="outl-add-right-info">
        <p class="info-top">
        <span class="user-name">Daffy Duck</span>
        <span>ACME International</span>
        <span>Manager</span>
        </p>
        <p class="address-info"></p>
        <span> +122323i9092<span class="grey-text">UIofcio</span>
        <p>daffy@acme.org</p>
        <p>666, 5th Avenue</p>
        <p>New York</p>
        <p>www.daffysite.com</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outl-add
{
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.outl-add-top
{
    height: 25px;
    background-color: orange;
}

.outl-add-left-vert
{
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 35px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.outl-add-right-info
{
    height: 200px;
    float; left;
    background-color: #eee;
}

p.info-top
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p.info-top span
{
    display: block;
}

.user-name
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.grey-text
{
    color: #ccc;
}
```

Hope that helps you out some. If you have any questions about anything used here, ask them in comments or a new question relative to the problem you have :)